Clickhouse ignores IP-address of Kafka
I run a ClickHouse DB in a docker container from image clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.8.2.7-alpine.
I run Kafka in another docker container. Its IP is 10.200.0.1
However as soon as I create a table:
CREATE TABLE storage_1
(
  storage_name String,
  total_size UInt64,
  free_size UInt64,
  updated_at DateTime('UTC')
)
ENGINE = Kafka()
SETTINGS
kafka_broker_list = '10.200.0.1:9092',
kafka_topic_list = 'topic-dev',
kafka_num_consumers = 1,
kafka_group_name = 'consumer-group-1',
kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow';

I notice that ClickHouse starts looking for Kafka at localhost:9092
It can be seen from the ClickHouse logs in the container:
$ docker exec -it ...
9021a1776e81:/# grep "9092" -r /var/log/
/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log:2024.12.20 15:33:42.792007 [ 374 ] {} <Error> StorageKafka (epcs_storage_1): [rdk:FAIL] [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: localhost:9092: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
...

It's also interesting that the Kafka-container can be pinged from the ClickHouse container.
9021a1776e81:/# ping 10.200.0.1
PING 10.200.0.1 (10.200.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.200.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
...

So there should be no problem to connect to it. Why doesn't ClickHouse do it?

According to this closed issue on the ClickHouse repository, you are missing setting KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS in your Kafka configuration.
After using the following example docker-compose.yml for setting up Zookeeper and Kafka, I no longer saw the error you were seeing.
docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.4
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.4
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

For the table creation, I referenced the kafka hostname and port defined in the example docker compose file:
CREATE TABLE storage_1
(
  storage_name String,
  total_size UInt64,
  free_size UInt64,
  updated_at DateTime('UTC')
)
ENGINE = Kafka(
   'kafka:29092',
   'topic-dev',
   'consumer-group-1',
   'JSONEachRow'
);

I did not see the error in the logs after executing:
select * from storage_1 SETTINGS stream_like_engine_allow_direct_select = 1;

Hope this helps.

You don't explain how you start/initialize Clickhouse so that it "sees" kafka.
I tried your solution and it turned out that it doesn't "see" kafka.

My solution is very dirty but it worked for my case.
I thought if Clickhouse looks for Kafka at localhost no matter what IP I specify during table creation then I must deceive it.
So I copied the /etc/hosts file from the running Clickhouse container and created a new file based on it replacing localhost IP address with 10.200.0.1
my-hosts:
10.200.0.1       localhost
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10.201.0.2      567d8beac3fc

And mounted it in docker-compose.yml
services:
  clickhouse:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.8.2.7-alpine
    container_name: clickhouse_container
    volumes:
      - ./my-hosts:/etc/hosts
    ports:
      - 8123:8123
      - 9000:9000

After that messages started landing in the corresponding table
